# Is this schematic on the track to create a AC clipper voltage and current regulator?

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator, ac

Good evening

I'm trying to make a "clipper" circuit for an AC Voltage source that feeds 2 6V light bulbs rated at 10W and 5W.

Problem is that the generator at idle speed produces 4V and at maximum RPM produces from 12V to 14V

My first approach was to put a 1.5mH coil in series in order to raise the inductive reactance as the generator goes to maximum output.

But I also saw the "poor mans square wave generator" using 2 zener diodes and try to come up with this circuit.

Maximum output of the circuit should be limited always at 6V and current no more than 2.5A

The circuit detects the overvoltage when D1 or D2 starts conducting, biasing Q1 or Q2 depending on the stage of the sine wave. This creates a Vdrop of 0.7 on the main line (So V Output= (6.8V (zener)+ 0.7 Zener forward) - 0.7V (Transistor) = 6.8V. The 50 ohm resistors are wrong, the idea is to make 50mA go into the base considering a transistor gain of 50 (so 50 mA x 50 hfe = 2.5A) at 6.8V I need R2 and R3 to be around 136 ohm

This circuit should work as expected or can have mishaps? Also I need to choose a transistor that can handle the reverse voltage when the sine wave it´s opposing the current path of the transistor, if I cannot, I consider putting a 1N4001 diode in the emitter of the NPN and the collector of the PNP, thus lowering another 0.7V at the output (6.1V final).

Any thoughts?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Bad plan.  Use LED 3V luminaire with a buck charger to boost current and reduce voltage. Diode bridge for the input with e-Cap.   Go shopping.

Comment: Thanks but this is a moped and the ground is the chassis of the bike so I cannot put a bridgde rectifier without making an exclusive DC ground out of the bridge rectifier. Also led lights work good on the rear tail but not good on the front lamp. Also the horn needs to be AC to work. So my idea is to clip the AC. Any toughts? My alternative to what you consider is to make a voltage doubler using a single diode and a eCap that way I can share the chassis of the moped as common AC and DC ground

Comment: All designs need to start with a good block diagram and DC resistance of every load in order to compute power losses for voltage limits.

Comment: Questions: 1) Is the 4 V to 14 V RMS, peak, or peak-to-peak?  2) What is the relationship between either of the generator terminals and the chassis GND?

Comment: voltage is peak. -/+4V -/+14V RMS not 2V or 7V amplitude (Measure given by a DMM in VAC setting. One of the generator terminals goes to chassis the other to the main wiring. The equivalent total resistance of the load is 2.4 ohm.